# How in PhpStorm 2021 to move into factory declarations?

Tags: phpstorm

Working with laravel 9 site in PhpStorm 2021 I
having line with factory :

```
\App\Models\Item::factory(Item::class)->make([
...
```

I would like to open content of database/factories/ItemFactory.php file, but

With selection Right popup menu=> Go to =>Implementations I have
_ide_helper_models.php file (I have barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper: ^2.12 installed) opened with code :

```
* @method static \Database\Factories\ItemFactory factory(...$parameters)
...
```

If there is a way to move to ItemFactory.php ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not via Ctrl+Click or Go to | Implementations, unfortunately: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/1209#issuecomment-815754610

You can perhaps invoke Navigate > Class and paste there `ItemFactory` - that should show you 2 ItemFactory classes, one in the helper file, and one that you're looking for.